# How do I navigate between List and Item?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to open an item from my list but my item code is in another js. When I try to use onPress method there is no action. Also I am using Swipeout.

Here is my JobList.js where I am rendering the list of my items.

```
class JobList extends Component {
  onJobDetails = (job) => {
    this.props.navigate('JobDetails', job);
  }
  render() {
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    var renderJobs = () => {
      return this.props.jobs.map((job) => {
        return (
          <JobItem 
            key={job._id} 
            title={job.title} 
            shortDescription={job.shortDescription} 
            logo={job.avatar} 
            company={job.company} 
            id={job._id}
            dispatch={this.props.dispatch}
            onPress={() => this.onJobDetails(job)}
          />
        )
      })
    }
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ScrollView>
          {renderJobs()}
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    );
  }
};
```

And here is my JobItem.js

```
class JobItem extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Swipeout {...swipeSettings}>
        <View style={styles.jobContainer}>
          <View>
            <Text style={styles.postTitle}>{this.props.title}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.postShortDescription}>{this.props.shortDescription}</Text>
          </View>
          <View>
          <Image 
            style={styles.postLogo} 
            source={{uri: '' + this.props.logo + ''}}/>
          </View>
        </View>
      </Swipeout>
    )
  }
};
```

Any idea how shall I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass `onPress` prop to the *child component* in order for it to work.

```
<Swipeout {...swipeSettings}>
   <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={this.props.onPress}>
     //... other children here
   </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
</Swipeout>
```